# File permissions denied when unzipped with java application, manually works fine

Tags: java, file, permissions

So I have two applications.

- 1) Launcher application to download client application versions
  (v2, v3, v3, etc).

  - 2) A client that the end user uses.

The workflow is basically to open the launcher, and select a client version to run.

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(revision.getPath() + "/" + AutoUpdate.OSX_EXE);
AutoUpdate.process = processBuilder.inheritIO().start();
```

The client uses jxBrowser and requires binaries it needs to download/extract. However when I download the .zip and unzip and set file permissions for the executable and run it from within the launcher, it doesn't work.

But when I download the version .zip and unzip it myself and run it without the launcher, it works just fine?

This is a java application compiled into native using excelsiorjet.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
    Caused by: com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractorException: Failed to extract Chromium binaries into /var/folders/kb/f884blms2g56m8xscqnsg9jh0000gn/T/jxbrowser-chromium-60.0.3112.113.6.16
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor.extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPC.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPC.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPC$a.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/var/folders/kb/f884blms2g56m8xscqnsg9jh0000gn/T/jxbrowser-chromium-60.0.3112.113.6.16/7zr-mac": error=13, Permission denied
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.XZExtractor.extract(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.b.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.<unknown>(Unknown Source)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/var/folders/kb/f884blms2g56m8xscqnsg9jh0000gn/T/jxbrowser-chromium-60.0.3112.113.6.16/7zr-mac": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.xz.XZ.decompress(Unknown Source)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
```

Here's my code changing the permissions:

```
    if(AutoUpdate.OS.equalsIgnoreCase("OSX")){
        File exe = new File(localPath + AutoUpdate.OSX_EXE);
        exe.setReadable(true);
        exe.setExecutable(true);
        exe.setWritable(true);
        File folder = new File(localPath + "rt");
        folder.setReadable(true);
        folder.setExecutable(true);
        folder.setWritable(true);
    }
    else{
        File exe = new File(localPath + AutoUpdate.WINDOWS_EXE);
        exe.setReadable(true);
        exe.setExecutable(true);
        exe.setWritable(true);
        File folder = new File(localPath + "rt");
        folder.setReadable(true);
        folder.setExecutable(true);
        folder.setWritable(true);
    }
```

Comment: Does user that you use to run Java application has permissions for `/var/folders/kb` directory?

Comment: I believe that one of the libraries makes that folder/directory, so I'm not sure if it does or not. What's weird is if I just download + unzip the application normally, it'll create that folder just fine. However if I unzip & run the application from within the wrapper launcher, it gives me an access denied.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue at the MAC machine through the Build. If I run it through STS/Eclipse it works fine. I used the following:

- JRE - jre1.8.0_232_windows (OpenJDK Server VM
  Corretto-8.232.09.1) and Corretto-8.232.09.2 at MAC,
- JxBrowser version 7.3,
- MAC 10.14 (Mojave) 
  I have resolved the issue by giving executable permission to the \lib folder (where my jxBrowser files placed). \bin folders permission code is already there. You can refer to the following code.

  ```
  if(OSDetector.isMacOSX()) {
      String binPath = new File(new File(lJreVersion, "bin").toString()).getAbsolutePath();
      String libPath = new File(new File(lJreVersion, "lib").toString()).getAbsolutePath();
      logger.info("getSpecifiedJavaExecutable() => " + binPath);
      setExecutable(binPath);
      setExecutable(libPath);
          }



  private void setExecutable(String path){        
      File folder = new File(path);
      File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
      for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
      if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
          System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
          listOfFiles[i].setExecutable(true);
      } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
          System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
      }
  }
  ```